# Replacing 2nd column of text file with different value (regex)

Tags: java, javascript, python, regex, notepad++

So I have a file, it's like

```
2587, 1, 104, 971;
2586, 1, 104, 971;
2585, 1, 104, 971;
2584, 1, 104, 971; 
2584, 1, 104, 971;
2584, 1, 104, 971;
2584, 1, 104, 971;
2584, 1, 104, 971;
2583, 1, 104, 971;
2582, 1, 104, 971;
2582, 1, 104, 971;
```

I have to change it to,

```
2587, 2, 104, 971;
2586, 2, 104, 971;
2585, 2, 104, 971;
2584, 2, 104, 971;
2584, 2, 104, 971;
2584, 2, 104, 971;
2584, 2, 104, 971;
2584, 2, 104, 971;
2583, 2, 104, 971;
2582, 2, 104, 971;
2582, 2, 104, 971;
```

I am trying to use regex but am  not able to select the 2nd column , I used this ,`([^,.]*)` , any pointers?

Comment: In Notepad++? Just press `Alt` (keep it down) and select the column with mouse, then simply write `2`...

Answer (score 1):

Python solution:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.rstrip().split(', ')
        columns[1] = '2'           #column[1] is the second column
        print ", ".join(columns).rstrip()
```

If the file is not huge:

```
import re
with open('filename') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print re.sub(r'(\d+,\s*)\d+,',r'\g<1>2,', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you can do:

```
search what : ^(\d+, \s*)\d+,
replace with: ${1}2,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "2587, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2586, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2585, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2584, 1, 104, 971; \n"
            + "2584, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2584, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2584, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2584, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2583, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2582, 1, 104, 971;\n"
            + "2582, 1, 104, 971;";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+,\\s*(\\d+),\\s*\\d+,\\s*\\d+;");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        String output = m.group().replaceAll(m.group(1), "2");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

But I think you should not use regex for this process .You could use split method in java then change the second element of array.